# How to call a method that takes in a string?

Tags: java

I am trying to save a .txt file where the user chooses using JFileChooser.

I have 3 methods

Thing 1 gets the file path and stores it into a string called File1.

Thing 2 requires this string in order to save the file in the correct location.

However when I run thing2 in the GUI ActionPerformed it gives me an error as it requires a string to be passed in. I pass in "String File1" however it doesnt work.

thing1

```
JFileChooser chooser;
        String choosertitle = null;
        String File1 = null;

chooser = new JFileChooser(); 
chooser.setCurrentDirectory(new java.io.File("."));
chooser.setDialogTitle(choosertitle);
chooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);

chooser.setAcceptAllFileFilterUsed(true);

if (chooser.showOpenDialog(this) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) { File1 = chooser.getCurrentDirectory() + "";
  }
else {
  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"No Selection ");

  }

    fileTextField.setText(File1);
return File1;
```

thing 2

```
      String nameOfFile = (""); 
    String choice = comboBox.getSelectedItem() + "";

  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,File1);


    if ("All Messages".equals(choice)){
        nameOfFile = ("Messages");  
    } else if 
        ("All Email Address".equals(choice)){
         nameOfFile = ("Address Book");  
    }

    File f = new File (File1 + nameOfFile+ ".txt");
    FileWriter fw;
    try {
        fw = new FileWriter(f);
        fw.write("This is a file created by Joe ");
        fw.close();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Export.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }


    boolean allFieldsCheck = !choice.equals("Please Select What You Would Like To Export") && !fileTextField.equals(""); 
    if (allFieldsCheck == false) {
        InputError ipe = new InputError();
        ipe.setVisible(true);
    } else {
        //add new message 
    }
```

ActionPerformed

```
private void exportButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                             

       thing2(String File1);

    }
```

all i want the above code to do is get the location of where the user wants to save the file and then save it there.

Any help would be grateful as I am new to this

Comment: `thing2(String File1);` means "pass in a new undefined string named `File1`". If `File1` is already defined, just pass in `File1` instead of `String File1`. The method signature takes care of the type of the argument, not the caller. Also, you should be more descriptive of the actual problem. "doesn't work" is not a problem statement. You should also show the actual method signatures, not just the content of the methods.

Comment: Actually, `thing2(String File1);` doesn't really mean anything, it's just a syntax error. In the actual arguments to a method only expressions (including variables) can appear, not type names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to modify the `exportButtonActionPerformed()` method:

```
private void exportButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                             
    thing2(File1);
}
```

but the variable `File1` defined in *thing1* has to be visible from this method, example:

```
public class AClass
{
    /* declared here in order to be visible both from thing1 and to ActionPerformed */
    private String File1 = null;

    /* thing1 */
    public void AMethod() {
        JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser(); 
        chooser.setCurrentDirectory(new java.io.File("."));
        chooser.setDialogTitle(choosertitle);
        chooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);

        chooser.setAcceptAllFileFilterUsed(true);

        if (chooser.showOpenDialog(this) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
            File1 = chooser.getCurrentDirectory() + "";
            fileTextField.setText(File1);
        } else
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"No Selection ");
    }

    /* ... */

    /* ActionPerformed */
    private void exportButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                             
        thing2(File1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should just call it like this:

```
private void exportButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    thing2(File1);
}
```

(BTW: A bit more Java-like naming would make it easier to follow.)

Answer (score 0):

First define your variable `File1` and then pass it to your method.

```
String file1 = "file path";  // variable name should be start with small case
thing2(file1);
```